# Why won't the /scan topic display rounded values?

Tags: lidar, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ros-hydro, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a student at a university of applied sciences, working on a robot that uses the Hokuyo UBG-04LX-F01 LIDAR.

The robot that I use runs on Ubuntu 12.0.4.5 with ROS Hydro Medusa.

The LIDAR of this robot supposedly has a minimum detection range of 20 millimetres and a maximum detection range of 5600 millimetres. This LIDAR is already installed on the robot and it is publishing data to the /scan topic with sensor_msgs/LaserScan messages.

However, when I echo the content of the /scan topic with the rostopic echo /scan command, it shows the following data:

```
seq: 75922
  stamp: 
    secs: 1522051099
    nsecs: 302610304
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: -1.50330114365
angle_max: 1.49716520309
angle_increment: 0.00613592332229
time_increment: 2.44140628638e-05
scan_time: 0.0250000003725
range_min: 0.019999999553
range_max: 5.59999990463
ranges: [<omitted for readability>]
intensities: []
```

This output shows that the LIDAR has a minimum range of 0.019999999553 metres. Why such a strange value? Is this due to rounding errors between integers and floats?
The same thing goes for other fields like the angle_min and angle_max, which are configured with an angle of -1.5 and 1.5 radians respectively.

I notice a comparable thing with the turtlebot, running in a gazebo simulation on ubuntu 16.0.4.4 with ROS Kinetic Kame, which shows a minimum range of 0.449999988079 (range_min: 0.449999988079).

Could somebody explain what is going on here? Why can't the output of the /scan topic have rounded values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286682/why-won%27t-the-/scan-topic-display-rounded-values?/) by [Lando](https://answers.ros.org/users/34327/lando/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glm](https://answers.ros.org/users/34037/glm/) on 2019-09-09**:
Like somebody should send a PR to round values to two decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm slightly confused, because what you show are exactly 'rounded values'. What you mean I believe is why there are so many decimals, and why those numbers are not 'nice' numbers (ie: `0.4999987003..` instead of `0.5`).

> Is this due to rounding errors between integers and floats?

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, integers have nothing to do with this. But `float` and `double` do indeed have a maximum number of significant digits they can encode. For `float` (or a single precision floating point number) this is about 7, for `double`, this is about 15 to 16 (that is total number of significant digits, not just 'after the comma').

So for a `float32` you can only realistically use the first 7 decimals.

A [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) uses `float32` for all fields. You could ask whether it wouldn't have been better to use `float64`, but for all intents and purposes `5.59999990463` *is* equal to `5.600000..` (unless you start multiplying it with large values). Chances are that in most cases, the uncertainty (or noise) contributed by other (sub)systems will be worse than those 7 significant digits can encode, and this loss of precision won't matter much. That is not always the case though, and for those, the extra 7 digits that `float64` provides may be important.

If you want to know more about this, some references:

- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)
- [wikipedia/Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)
- [wikipedia/Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

The first link is a simpler explanation of the [original article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Note that this is actually completely off-topic for this site: it's not a ROS problem at all.

**Comment by [Lando](https://answers.ros.org/users/34327/lando/) on 2018-03-27**:
Thank you for the quick response. I never encountered any issues with floating point arithmetic until I started working with ROS, where a LaserScan message has values with many decimal places. I thought it was a ROS issue as the turtlebot shows similar behaviour.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:\

> I never encountered any issues with floating point arithmetic until I started working with ROS,

what sort of issues are you referring to here?

`rostopic echo` not displaying 'nice' numbers is not really an issue.

**Comment by [Lando](https://answers.ros.org/users/34327/lando/) on 2018-03-27**:
Indeed, the noise is far worse than the floating point precision, it is not about just 'nice' numbers. The problem is that I cannot explain why there is a difference between the datasheet and what is posted on a rostopic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
That I can't help you with I'm afraid (and would be a new question).

You could always try to see what the situation is 'at the source' (ie: the driver), to make sure the conversion to `float32` (if there is any) does not result in a catastrophic loss of precision.

**Comment by [Lando](https://answers.ros.org/users/34327/lando/) on 2018-03-27**:
It is most presumably due to floating point precision, I have marked your answer as correct. Thank you for your time!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
If your question was really about why your datasheet states something, but you're seeing something else, then I believe this was an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info).

The reason you're seeing 'strange' nrs on the `scan` topic is most definitely due to limited precision in floating point nrs.